# Detecting maximum capabilities of a computer from debian

Tags: memory, debian

I have Debian installed on an old laptop (dell inspiron 640m) that I would like to use as a small server at home. Sadly, it only has 1GB of DDR2 RAM at 533MHz, and the basic Debian OS uses about 600MB of the RAM when it has started (at the point I can ssh into it).

So, I was wondering, is there any way (apart from crawling the internet, which im doing now, but not getting very far with as of yet) I can detect:

- the maximum ram installable
- the maximum speed the bus supports
- the maximum speed ram I can install that will still run on the bus (such as 1333MHz DDR3 down to 533MHz DDR2)

This is the current configuration (according to dmidecode):

```
# dmidecode 2.9
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x1000
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 512 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_A
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: DDR
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00000000000000
        Serial Number: F31A5C0D
        Asset Tag: 430653
        Part Number: M4 70T6554CZ3-CD5

Handle 0x1101, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x1000
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 512 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM_B
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: DDR
        Type Detail: Synchronous
        Speed: 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
        Manufacturer: CE00000000000000
        Serial Number: F31A5C7D
        Asset Tag: 430653
        Part Number: M4 70T6554CZ3-CD5
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use http://www.dell.com/support/ support page and put in the service tag(should be at the bottom of your laptop), then look for system specification or manual.